# Msal Node Extensions returns a new token every time

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am using the MSAL Node Extensions > file persistence cache to store tokens, but it always returns a new token; it's not returning a token from the cache.

I am returning the file persistent cache from my wrapper(see below) and passing that as cache parameter >

// auth object

```
const authObj ={
       auth:{ clientId: " removed",
        authority: "removed ",
        clientSecret: " removed"
},
"scopes": [removed]
    }

// call to wrapper
```

const fpCache = await getFilePersistentCache("fp","12345")

```
 const authConfigForToken = { authObj, cache:{
               cachePlugin: fpCache
            }}

// call msal with cache
 const authConfigForToken = { authObj, cache:{
               cachePlugin: fpCache
            }}
const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(authConfigForToken)
// pass in scope 
const clientCredentialRequest = {
            scopes,
          };

cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)  ........
```

** node extensions wrapper **

```
import { FilePersistenceWithDataProtection, DataProtectionScope,PersistenceCreator, PersistenceCachePlugin } from '@azure/msal-node-extensions'

export const filePersistentCache = (cacheName:string,optionalEntropy:string)=>{
    const path= `./data/${cacheName}` 
    const persistence = FilePersistenceWithDataProtection.create(path,
    DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine, optionalEntropy).then(fp => {return fp})    
    return persistence;
}

export const initiliazeFilePersistentCache = (filePersistCache:FilePersistenceWithDataProtection)=>{ 
   return new PersistenceCachePlugin(filePersistCache);
}

export const getFilePersistentCache = async (cacheName:string,optionalEntropy:string)=>{
   const fp =  initiliazeFilePersistentCache(await filePersistentCache(cacheName,optionalEntropy)
   .then( item=>{
    return  item
   }))
   return fp
}
```

I tried articles and intructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node-extensions, I get a token but its just a new one everytime.